# Why WordPress takes time to make request to save post?

Tags: custom-field, performance, save-post

I have around 50 post meta fields, each meta field have different values.
I have noticed when saving posts, it takes around 3 to 4 seconds to make request.

Why?

Comment: Is this a wordpress.com question? If so you should contact Support/Happiness, this site's for development questions for .org installs

Comment: i know i should not use this tag, but when i ask a question it didnt allow me to submit. i am new here.

Comment: You should choose tags that are relevant to your question, wordpress.com questions are off topic here and get closed

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure, but looks like Wordpress doesn't have a method to update custom fields in batches, so, 1 query to the DB per field.